# How to get _id from listView (database) [android]

Tags: android, sql, android-listview

I have a problem with receiving _ID value when an item is clicked on listView.

I have this code:

```
List<SavedSearch> values =  mydb.getAllSavedSearches();

      ArrayAdapter<SavedSearch> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SavedSearch>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
      //adding it to the list view.
      obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      obj.setAdapter(adapter);

      obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
     long id) {
```

And my problem is that i want in onItemClick to somehow get the _ID value from database of clicked item in listView. *int position* and *long id* both are returning just position on the list. 
Thanks for help, and I can say that any of previous topics helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a database I would suggest you **do not** use an ArrayAdapter and instead use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). Then simply call the method `getItemId()` from your `CursorAdapter` to retrieve the id of an item at a given position. So, do this:

```
CursorAdapter adapter = new CursorAdapter(Context yourAppContext, Cursor yourDBCursor, false);
obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
obj.setAdapter(adapter);
obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
long id) {

    adapter.getItemId(position); // This is the _ID value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the suggestion. I am not sure this will solve the issue.
**Method 1:**
Whenever you load the listView just set the id for the row and you can get the id from onItemClikListener method

**Method 2:**
Add an texView (set visibility gone) and set text as your id and get id using `getText()` method

**Note**

Don't use position this is always changing when the listview is reCycling.